# drag img into rect?

Tags: drag-and-drop, kineticjs

In Kineticjs I want to drag an img into a rect shape.

I was wondering if anyone could tell me how to do that?
I know how to drag a shape or image around, but i want to drag the img into the shape.

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-fill-with-kineticjs/  You can set the background of a shape by firing a .on(mouseover ) event on the shape and then removing the image. And yes, please build up some code for us to see as Ani says. Place it in a jsfiddle if possible.

Comment: The other thing you could do is replace the rectangle with the image and a rectangle in it's background.

Comment: thanks guys, I've added the jsfiddle link, thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Here is the http://jsfiddle.net/Ps3TU/ of what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to drag the darth vader image into the rectangle, and have the image show up in there. Ideally, I'd like to have multiple boxes eventually where you can drag different images into. Most of the code here was from: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ps3TU/5/ is a step toward something you'd want to do.

```
  darthVaderImg.on('dragmove', function () {
      var userPos = stage.getUserPosition();
      if(rectShape.intersects(userPos)){
            rectShape.setFillPatternImage(this.getImage());
            this.hide();
            rectShape.setFillPatternOffset(this.getWidth(), 70);
      }
  });
```

But what you're really looking to do is something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8Vdht/3/

```
darthVaderImg.on('dragmove', function () {
 var userPos = stage.getUserPosition();
  if(rectShape.intersects(userPos)){
    this.setX(rectShape.getX());
    this.setY(rectShape.getY());
    this.setWidth(rectShape.getWidth());
    this.setHeight(rectShape.getHeight());
  }
  else {
    this.setWidth(savedWidth);
    this.setHeight(savedHeight);
    this.setImage(imageObj);
  }
  layer.draw();
});
```

The thing is, you can't (yet) just place an image (inside) a rectangle and later extract it all that easily. So you need to resort to a trick, which resizes the image and makes it look like it's in the rectangle. This fixes the position of the image and you get to move it outside of the rectangle.

Comment: If you're looking to dynamically place images into various other shapes you have to do a lot of work with cropping images to make them fit. This solution was only for rectangles, since images are saved as rectangles.

Comment: You sir...are awesome, it's more or less what I was trying to get at. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to help, I've been trying to create some insert/extract function for images into shapes, but I've reverted to this simpler way.